# Printing out the array position from a number input by a user

Tags: java, arrays

Question:

I need to create an array that holds 1000 integers ranging from 1-100. I then need to ask the user for an input and find out if the number the user has input is present in the array. If its not, then I have to output the message that it is not in the array.

- I populated the array with random numbers, just need to find out how to search for the number in the array. I tried using a while loop to condition the for loop, but cant because the random generator and searcher would be in the same loop. Is there a way to linearly search for the number?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numbers = new int[1000];

        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());



     for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 1)
        {
            numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: first need to populate the array with random (1000 for loop) and after check if number is in array (can loop again). So 2 loops and no while (while also a loop but think see the point) ...

Comment: You are mixing up the random number generation and the searching, all in one loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numbers = new int[1000];
        boolean found = false;

        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 1)
        {
            numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random()*100);   
        }
        
        for(int i =0; i < 1000; i++){
            if(numbers[i] == n){
                found = true;
                System.out.println(numbers[i] + " Appears first at index " + i); 
                break;
            }
        }
    
        if(!found){System.out.println("Number " + n + " is not in the list");}
}
```